# EF Core without additional repository pattern

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, ef-core-3.0

There seems to be a certain movement advocating that when we use EF Core we should avoid creating a Repository & Unit of work pattern because EF Core already implement those two and we can leverage this implicit implementation. That would be great because implementing those patterns is not always as straightforward as it would seem.

So here's the problem. When implementing repository the 'classic' way we have a place to put the code that builds our domain objects. Let me explain with an example; we have an Invoice and an InvoiceRow entities. Each Invoice has many InvoiceRows. I included only the navigational property for brevity.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceRow> InvoiceRows { get; }
}

public class InvoiceRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal RowPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now, my business object is an Invoice with its rows, and this should be the only way to manipulate the invoices.
When using 'explicit' repository we would do something like:

```
public class InvoicesRepo
{
    public AppDbContext AppDbContext { get; private set; }

    public Invoice Find(int id)
    {
        return

        AppDbContext.Invoices.Where(invoice => invoice.Id == id)
                    .Include(nameof(InvoiceRow))
                    .First();
    }
}
```

This restricts the access to the Invoice to the method [InvoicesRepo].Find(id)  that builds the invoice in the way that is expected by the domain logic code.

Is it possible to achieve this with bare EF Core? Maybe working with visibility of DbSets and/or additional features that I don't know? Since this seems to be quite a fundamental functionality of a full-blown repository, if it's not achievable, have I just destroyed the main argument of experts advocating for no (additional) repository when using EF Core?

Comment: It's not a current movement - authors, MVPs and DBAs always warned about this. One of the reasons is that nothing the "generic" repository does isn't already available, perhaps even better. For example, `DbSet.Find<T>()` will first check the cached entities before hitting the database to load a value. Besides, the code you posted is plain LINQ over EF, nothing specific to a repo. This doesn't restrict access in any way

Comment: Nothing says you should have just one DbContext for an entire application either. On the contrary, you should have one DbContext per scenario/use-case/bounded context, containing *only* the entities needed for that scenario. Those entities can contain just the properties needed for that scenario. Instead of an `AppDbContext` you should have an `Invoic*ing*Context`, a `SalesContext`, a `CatalogContext` etc. The same "entities" appear in all scenarios, eg. `Product` but the properties and operations they need are *very* different

Comment: Once you have your bounded context, specialised repositories make sense once again. The operations needed for invoicing are very different from sales or displaying an e-shop's catalog. A specialised repository can abstract complex multi-entity operations while calling the appropriate DbContext. It could also use Dapper or another micro-ORM for operations that *don't* need a full ORM, eg to `UPDATE` multiple records with a single query.

Comment: Having multiple DbContext is very interesting just sounds a bit pionieristic to me. I haven't seen any example of such a use so far. The solution have to be studied, it's not just buy, unbox and use. Maybe you can provide me some link to an example of this type

Comment: Once again, it's nothing new. The concepts were formalised in DDD though (which itself is 16 years old). It's the normal way to work with any ORM. I already offered an example - a Product is a completely different entity in Invoicing, Sales, Catalogs. What does invoicing care about pictures? What do sales care about the ledger accounts used for a specific product? If you try to create one Product entity to cover all scenarios you'll end up with a monstrosity

Comment: The problem is that almost all tutorials show toy applications, with toy contexts that can fit into a single DbContext. That doesn't mean they should though, or that this is practical in production. In fact, when EF first came out, startup with big DbContexts was horrendously slow, so people had to break them up sooner or later. This wasn't mentioned in any tutorials though

Comment: However  I still don't have an answer to the question: where do I put the code of my Find method?  An Invoice always contains its rows; i cannot leave the 'include' method to the client-part. That way, the invoice you can get from the DbContext may or may not contain the rows depending whether you called "Include" or not. Instead, there should be just one way to get an invoice as a domain object. That way should return the invoice with its rows.

Comment: To make it even clearer, let say that i implemented logical deletion of rows. An invoice's row that has a certain value is considered deleted and should not appear in the collection of rows. I want this filtering to be implemented in a non-duplicated way. So I have to have a place to  gather all the domain-objects building, even if it's only 'plain linq over EF' . Linq makes it short but the shortness shouldn't encourage us to repeat the same logic all over. It's duplication and a good repository is something that minimizes this.

Comment: What you describe has nothing to do with `gather all the domain-objects building`, unless you mean *querying*. The current generic repository anti pattern doesn't encapsulate entity building either. You still have to define your classes *outside* the repository (unless you use nested classes), still have to configure the entities inside the DbContext's OnModelBuilding.

Comment: Logical deletion, you mean the anti-pattern known as soft-deletes? First, don't. [Oren Eini, the maintainer of NHibernate at the time, explained why that's awful back in 2009](https://ayende.com/blog/4157/avoid-soft-deletes). **NO** business user asks for fake deletes with broken constraints and references. They ask for change history, state changes etc that are far more complex to apply than simply flipping a flag. Second, EF Core offers global query filtering for this. So even if you leak an implementation detail into the domain like soft-deletes, you can at least keep part of it hidden away

Comment: That's why I say this is nothing new - all of those things have been discussed already, over a decade ago. Optimistic concurrency, disconnected operations, 2 decades ago. Then they got forgotten, some lazy generators, frameworks and tutorials just published the implementations without giving *any* explanation of what was needed or not, and the result is new developers littering their code with useless abstractions, wondering why eg the wrong queries get executed, or why that database transaction they used to implement "transaction-per-request" caused their web app to crawl to a stop

Comment: I basically agree with you, that's why my question. Unfortunately, i'm struggling to find practical documentation pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I find that strange as *all* good books and courses in the last 20 years describe those concepts. You won't find the explanations in newer cheap/free publishers and courses that simply regurgitate mantras just to get a "Recipe" book or free course out. Just because some books are that old doesn't mean they no longer apply - think of Martin Fowler's books on architecture, or Gregor Hohpe's book on EAI, distributed systems. Even Eric Evans' book on DDD is 16 years old.

Comment: I just found this blog post [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) by Oren Eini, again from 2009. He mentions the same problems, and additionally `the way that most people use a Repository more closely follows the DAO pattern, not the Repository pattern.`. Remember, he was the maintainer of NHibernate, one of the *most* influential people in OOP/ORM/DDD in the .NET world, whose articles and concepts get copied (without attribution) in new blogs, articles, books and courses.

Comment: That said, I still don't get what do you mean by "querying". Querying is something that you mostly do on the database. From the repository user perspective, the 'querying' is reduced to the Invoice Id; it doesn't query rows because rows are just a part of the business object that is an Invoice. The repository queries the database and presents the upper layer with the object already constructed. If the upper layer  all of them mess with the querying and don't have a single point to encapsulate the way a object is constructed, it's a problem. It this doesn't explain my point then i give up.

Comment: If you want a *good* course, check Julie Lerman's courses on Pluralsight, eg [Entity Framework in the Enterprise](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/entity-framework-enterprise-update). The last section is called `Understanding EF Encapsulation and the Great Repository Debates`. Julie Lerman literally [wrote the books on Entity Framework](https://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/3141)

Comment: in your example, the repository needs to be *specialized* to `Include()` the invoice items. And even that is just a single extra line. What you describe is a *specialized* repository, not the generic repository/Data Access Object everyone is warning against.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to specialize my repository? I took the course of Julie Lersman's (the part you indicated).She talks about generic repos vs other 'encapsulation' option but it seems to be just another type of repository with more focused  methods (InitializeCart instead of Insert). So my conclusion is that even people that talk about not having additional repositories end up with repositories. Sometimes they don't call them repositories so that they think they are doing something different. This way they end up with an application layer that doesn't even have a name.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to achieve this with bare EF Core? Maybe working with visibility of DbSets and/or additional features that I don't know?

Sure, accepting that the DbContext *is* your repository doesn't mean you can't make design decisions and you have to have use the default DbContext design.

You can add reusable data access code to your DbContext for convenience and consistency, eg methods like:

```
public Invoice FindInvoice(int id)
{
    this.Invoices.Where(invoice => invoice.Id == id)
                .Include(nameof(InvoiceRow))
                .First();
}
```

So for code that needs the standard shape of Invoice with InvoiceRows, they call this method.  But for code that needs some nonstandard shape, they still can access the DbSets or IQueryable methods and construct a custom query.

You can even eliminate the DbSet properties, to more strongly guide users to use your custom methods, like:

```
public IQueryable<Invoice> Invoices => this.Invoices.Include(nameof(InvoiceRow));
```

Then to get Invoices without InvoiceRows a consumer would either add a custom projection to this, something like

```
  db.Invoices.Where(i => i.CustomerID == custId).Select(i => new InvoiceDTO(i)).ToList();
```

or access the DbSet

```
 var invoice = db.Set<Invoice>().Find(invoiceId);
```

And you can organize the methods on your DbContext by having it implement various interfaces.

Comment: Great! What is InvoiceDTO? An object that takes an invoice as constructor parameter, it seems. Which pattern is this? It seems not efficient since it retrieves the invocies with rows then it selects them out. Doesn't it?

Comment: That was just a made-up example of a piece of code that might want an Invoice entities without the associated InvoiceRow entities.  Updated it to make it a little more sensible.

Comment: However I don't know how to eliminate DbSet property and still let a class be an entity, maybe the fluent API. I tried to reach the same purpose letting the DbSet be private.

Comment: Yes.  The Fluent API.  EG  `modelBuilder.Entity(typeof(Invoice));` will register Invoice as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just a preliminary answer based on *many* readings all around.

```
public class InvoiceQuery
{
    public AppDbContext AppDbContext { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Invoice Execute()
    {
        return AppDbContext
                .Invoices
                .Include(nameof(Invoice.InvoiceRows))
                .Where(invoice => invoice.Id == Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

My problem was that this is not substantially different from what we would have into a repository. That's from a practical point of view; from a theoretical point of view, this puts you on the right perspective while the repository is sort of misleading.
The reason why it's misleading is that there is no 1-1 association between entities and actions or queries that you can do on the database.  Even in this case, Invoice is not just invoice, but is Invoice plus InvoiceRows.  (By the way, I think that InvoiceQuery is a good name (and not InvoiceWithRowsQuery) because from a business logic point of view an invoice is a full-loaded invoice; an invoice with 0 rows is an empty invoice, not an partially-loaded invoice.)

So a query focuses on what you get, not on the entity you start from, because they can be more than one.
This "query" name is sort of counter-intuitive, because one would say that as you move towards the business logic, you stop seeing things like queries and you start seeing things like paramenters.  And actually we have parameters, "query" is only the name of the container.  Maybe we should call it Business Object Query, but it would be too long, but that's the meaning. So this query object is just a simple container for an EF Query; I will talk about this later on. In this class based implementation, besides being glorified as object, there is no addictional functionality. Maybe you would expect some additional functionality,  instead you have something less. This missing thing is that they are no associated with an entity anymore.  This is another counter-intuitive fact that proves that here we are dismantleing something: the contrived entity-repository view.

Having a so simple object poses a question. Why not a method on some related class? If we put it on the Entity, we go back to the repository-like organization, that seems flawed mainly because the missing 1-1 bla bla means that in many cases you couldn't tell which entity associate a query to. But some authors use a sort of 'container class' that is really no more than a container just it's not entitled to an entity (OrdersData for example).  If you like me like classes that have a clear purpose, this sends you shivers down the spine.  We started up saying that we have a solution that is better than the repository. That the repository has so many problems. We end up with a class that has "Data" in its name. How could a better solution be so lame?  It feels like the repository alternative is just a bunch of stuff, not a steady and well designed as expected.  On the other hand, this is just a way to collect queries (the same queries that you would have in a repository, the *very* same query that you would have in a query/command pattern...) under a name that is not that of an entity.
Yes, all this seems to boil down to a naming choice. Advocates of repository pattern and advocates of no-repository fiercely fighting each others. Then you look at the code, what it actually does. The code is the same and the names are all we are talking about.  That is: if you look what repositoriests do in their repositories and non-repositoriests do in their whatever (not always clear) classes, they do exaclty the same things. But this is just an impression, I've to time-proof it.

In the repository model, having a repository for entity with its methods was reassuring.  It provided a sort of scaffolding where to put all of the methods. Unfortunately that scaffolding seems to be too limitating, again because of the not 1-1 relation between entities and queries/commands.  Yet we have to say that the root entities like Invoice (in DDD speaking Invoice are root, InvoiceRows are aggregate) would fit quite well in repository-style organization.
For this reason, in this query based solution the flatness of the Query collection is not fully satisfying, and this is another reason why I think I want to further elaborate on this topic.